# Sequelize ORM: How to statically associate models to db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize on my ReactJS application to access my database. Follow the tutorial, below is my sequelize initializer used to load all models and make then available to `db`:

```
"use strict";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var basename = path.basename(__filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.js")[env];
var db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.database,
        config.username,
        config.password,
        config
    );
}

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (
            file.indexOf(".") !== 0 &&
            file !== basename &&
            file.slice(-3) === ".js"
        );
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

This is how a simple model looks like: TestModel.js

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let TestModel = sequelize.define("TestModel", {
        id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING(32), allowNull: false },
        description: { type: DataTypes.STRING(256) }
    });

    return TestModel;
};
```

And then I can normally use it inside my code:

```
   db.TestModel.find(...);
```

All running fine, until I need to prepare the production bundle.

I'm using webpack to prepare the production bundle that is delivered as a single file. When doing so, the model files are not any more available for importing at:

```
fs
        .readdirSync(__dirname)
        .filter(file => {
            return (
                file.indexOf(".") !== 0 &&
                file !== basename &&
                file.slice(-3) === ".js"
            );
        })
        .forEach(file => {
            var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
            db[model.name] = model;
        });

    Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
        if (db[modelName].associate) {
            db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
    });
```

.. and then there are no more models available to be used from `db`, what causes my database access code `db.TestModel.find(...);` to fail with the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Naturally no files were imported (there is just my bundle.js) and db does not contain the model definition.

So, I need a way to statically import the models, and here is my try:

```
import TestModel from "./TestModel.js";

.
.
.

db[TestModel.name].associate(db);
```

Althought this runs, it does not associate and I'm getting the same error at runtime.

How can I statically associate my models to sequelize db so that I can access then directy as `db.ModelName` ?